# find (and replace) n-th column in a LaTeX table using regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I have a string that is a LaTeX table. I'm trying to find the n-th (let's say third) column and wrapping everything inside, say `\emph{}` without matching the delimiting dollar signs.

I'm looking for the first `&...&` which is second column. Then find the next `&...&` which is second grouping and by no coincidence a third column in the table.

My dummy example works but is a bit different, because it has text between two `&...&`. There's a little thing I will tackle at a later stage - I need to put `&` outside the `\emph{}` call using back- and forward-references.

```
xy <-  "This is &more or less& a match and here is &another one&.\nSecond line with &occurrance 1& and &occurrance 2&"
gsub("(&.*?&)|(.*?&)(.*)(&.*?&)", "\\1\\2\\3\\\\emph{\\4}", xy, perl = TRUE)
[1] "This is &more or less& a match and here is \\emph{&another one&}.\nSecond line with &occurrance 1& and \\emph{&occurrance 2&}"
```

When I kick it up a notch to a read set with LaTeX tables (bam!), it's a bit different. There are no characters between two `&...&`, which means that one `&` borders two columns. Having that in mind I removed the `(.*)`. No matter what I try, I can't get this to work. Any tips?

```
library(xtable)
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:5,])
x <- print.xtable(tli.table, print.results = FALSE, include.rownames = FALSE)

cat(x)
% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Thu Jul 26 14:13:39 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlllr}
  \hline
grade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\ 
  \hline
  6 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  43 \\ 
    7 & M & NO & BLACK &  88 \\ 
    5 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  34 \\ 
    3 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  65 \\ 
    8 & M & YES & WHITE &  75 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

gsub("(&.*?&)(&.*?&)", "\\1\\\\emph{\\2}", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is in LaTeX the same dollar sign character `$` end of column and also beginning of the next column? Another words: `0$123$456$789$0` means that `456` is a second column?

Comment: @Ωmega LaTeX' structure of a table line is `col1 $ col2 $ col3 \\\`, so \\ is end of line. There is no explicit "start line" character.

Comment: So first column does not start with `$` - correct? And the last one does not end with `$` as well...?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. See the example in my question. Text between first two \hline-s is a column row.

Comment: How about leading and trailing white-space characters?

Comment: What is `tli`? Your example is not reproducible (easily) unless I feed `x` into an object myself.

Comment: In you example I see `&` and not `$` between `\hline`s... Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you guys mistaking `&` and `$`? `&` is the column separator in a LaTeX table.

Comment: Boing. Gavin is right, `&` is name of the game, not `$`. Embarrassing. @Ωmega I'll edit my question, please stand by. @Gavin, I added `data(tli)`, it should now be reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming 1<sup>st</sup> column is `n <- 1` (and not `n <- 0`), the regex that you should use for replacement of n-th column should be:

```
(?m)^(?=[^&\n\r]*&)((?:[^&]*&){n-1})\\s*([^&]*?)\\s*(&|\\\\)
                                ↑
                                └ replace this n-1 with real number
```

and replacement string then has to be `\\1\\\\emph{\\2}\\3`.

So your replacement code is:

```
input <- "% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-0 package\n% Thu Jul 26 17:49:09 2012\n\\begin{table}[ht]\n\\begin{center}\n\\begin{tabular}{rlllr}\n  \\hline\ngrade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\\\ \n  \\hline\n  6 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  43 \\\\ \n    7 & M & NO & BLACK &  88 \\\\ \n    5 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  34 \\\\ \n    3 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  65 \\\\ \n    8 & M & YES & WHITE &  75 \\\\ \n   \\hline\n\\end{tabular}\n\\end{center}\n\\end{table}\n"

n <- 1
regex <- paste(c('(?m)^(?=[^&\n\r]*&)((?:[^&]*&){', n-1, '})\\s*([^&]*?)\\s*(&|\\\\)'), collapse='')
cat(gsub(regex, "\\1\\\\emph{\\2}\\3", input, perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this work, hang on. R needs \ have escaped, so \\1 is apt.

Comment: After removing the `$` this seems to work for the first line. Is there a way to convince regex to do the same in the rest of the lines?

Comment: If I add `(?m)^`, everything before the match disappears.

Comment: That's it, I had to use the one with white-spaces trimmed. Thank you, I will be accepting your answer tomorrow. I would like to let others chip in if they can provide a solution that can process first column as well.

Comment: Feel free to include that in your answer (the entire `gsub()` call).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - I have updated the answer with code that will work for any **n**, incl. 1 (1st column). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to wrap your column in `emph{}` before calling xtable:

```
data(tli)
tli[, 4] <- paste0("\\\\emph{", tli[, 4], "}")
```

Then your script as you had it:

```
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:5,])
x <- print.xtable(tli.table, print.results = FALSE, include.rownames = FALSE)
cat(x)
```

Produces the following, which should give the desired results:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.15.0 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Thu Jul 26 16:08:58 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlllr}
  \hline
grade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\ 
  \hline
  6 & M & YES & $\backslash$$\backslash$emph\{HISPANIC\} &  43 \\ 
    7 & M & NO & $\backslash$$\backslash$emph\{BLACK\} &  88 \\ 
    5 & F & YES & $\backslash$$\backslash$emph\{HISPANIC\} &  34 \\ 
    3 & M & YES & $\backslash$$\backslash$emph\{HISPANIC\} &  65 \\ 
    8 & M & YES & $\backslash$$\backslash$emph\{WHITE\} &  75 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility. This however does not work if you have an ANOVA table. They are often passed to xtable for pretty printing in LaTeX in which case, one has to work with an xtable object.